# Ajax request is never entering `success:function(resp){ ...}`

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

My ajax request is never entering `success:function(resp){ ...}`

I'm getting a response status of `200` and the `Json response` obtained is not null.

My ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/url/',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        pass_value: 0,
        req_time_last_ack_update: 0,
    },
    dataType: "json",

    success : function (resp) {
        // Compiler is never entering here [I checked with Mozilla debugger]
    },
    error: function(){
        ....
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me find the reason for this failure?

(Question edited for clarification)

Comment: is the space between success and : a typo here or does it exist in your code?

Comment: _I'm getting a response status of 200 and the Json response obtained is not null._ then what is the failure?

Comment: @Cruiser that syntax is fine. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nb9k8nfy/2/

Comment: compiler is not entering `success:function(resp){    }`. That's the problem

Comment: I think the owner of the question is trying to figure out why he cannot get into the success method of the Ajax request. Jithin can you confirm this?

Comment: @Turnip ok thanks. in some programming languages it wouldn't be.

Comment: Closing of `$.ajax({`  should  `});`  not  `}` . This is one of your mistake not only.

Comment: @Poonam In my actual code `});`  itself is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to step into this directly after the call it will not work. 
The Ajax request you are sending happens **Asynchronously**.

Only as soon as a response is received from the server (this could be several seconds later) you will see a breakpoint being hit (if you set one) inside the success method.

Comment: Are you stepping into the next line or continuing with the debug?

Comment: I kept break point for all statements inside `success`. Then, the code is never hit any break point. Also when I keep a break point at `success`, it's hit.

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside AND before `success`. Wait till you hit the first breakpoint and then press F8 on the keyboard. See if the second breakpoint is then hit

Comment: Thanks it was taking really long to enter inside `success`

Comment: Because it is waiting for a response from the server :) It all depends on how long it takes the client to receive a response from the server. Hence the importance of Asynchronous calls.